# What exactly is the meaning of "node" in Document Object Model (DOM)?

Tags: javascript, api, html, xml, dom

I've searched for the definition of a "node" in a programming language and I am still finding it hard to understand.

Could anyone advice me in simple, layman's terms:

What is a node?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979172/difference-between-node-object-and-element-object/9979779#9979779

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node

Comment: Have you read [Node (computer science) on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_%28computer_science%29)?

Comment: @jfriend00 - Thanks for the link... it really helped!

Comment: @amon - Yes, I have read that. Makes no sense to me.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_node.asp

Comment: It is a node in a hierarchical model (aka. tree). It can be root, branch and leaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Etymologically, a "node" is a "knot": think of a fisherman's net as "holes tied together with string", and then nodes are where the string is knotted. The term comes from graph theory in mathematics. If you think of a graph as a collection of points connected to each other by lines ("arcs"), then the points are called nodes. A tree is a special case of a graph in which a node can only have one "upwards" arc (to its "parent"). The DOM models a document as a tree: documents have a hierarchic structure in which sections contains sections contain sections, and a tree is a graph-theoretic representation of a hierarchy. So the parts of a document - the sections - are represented by nodes in the tree.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of an SGML language where DOM is typically used (i.e. HTML, XML), a node is the smallest piece of text that has semantic meaning. Nodes are arranged in a tree structure, with the document as the root node. Each node can have zero or more children.

There are several types of nodes:

- Document: this is the root node of the whole document. It represents the root of the SGML tree, one step above the root element (e.g. the `<html>` tag). This is done so it can contain metadata such as the DOCTYPE.
- Element: this is a "tag" e.g. `<div>` or `<MyXmlElement>`. Elements can have subnodes, including attributes and other elements.
- Attribute: This is one key/value pair inside an element. For example, the `class` specifier: `<div class="SomeCssClass">`
- CDATA: "loose" text: `<div>This CDATA is a child of the div element.</div>`

Answer (score 1):

You can safely compare it to a map of a subway system, e.g. the London Underground:

[image: London Underground Map]
(http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mappa_della_metropolitana_di_Londra)

A node is a stop, an edge is the connection between stations. That's about it with general graphs. However, there are special graphs with more, interesting properties, like Trees:

[image: a Tree]
(https://hbfs.wordpress.com/2013/05/14/average-node-depth-in-a-full-tree/)

Nodes in a tree are either (a) the root (think <html>) or (b) have exactly one parent. They *may* also have one or many children nodes, which have them as a parent, so we get exactly one path to the root for every node in the graph.

The DOM is a tree.

Answer (score -1):

The Node object represents a single node in the document tree.

A node can be an element node, an attribute node, a text node, or any other of the node types explained in the [Node Types chapter](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp).

[image]

Comment: Downvoter cares to comment?